# When does RMI runtime disconnect client connections?

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, rmi, serversocket

I want to know how connections are handled?

Should the client make explicit calls to release RMI resources?

Please answer this question with respect to custom sockets and default RMI sockets.

Answer (score 0):

> When does RMI runtime disconnect client connections?

Whenever it likes, subject to the various [RMI system properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/javarmiproperties.html) and [`sun.rmi` system properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html).

> I want to know how connections are handled?

Invisibly, by the RMI runtime system.

> Should the client make explicit calls to release RMI resources?

It isn't necessary. RMI has Distributed Garbage Collection (DGC): that is usually sufficient to take care of that.

> Please answer this question with respect to custom sockets and default RMI sockets.

The release of RMI resources doesn't have anything to do with custom sockets or default RMI sockets, and the use of custom socket factories doesn't have any effect on RMI connection pooling, if implemented according to the specifications.

Comment: Isn't there any documentation on how connection pooling is handled?

Comment: There is only the system property documentation mentioned above. The RMI Specification is silent about connections.